# Google Calendar API gives 403 Quota exceeded error when limit is not exceeded

Tags: api, google-calendar-api

I have a problem with the Google Calendar API.
We are using the API with OAuth2 authentication in Python code.

It was working fine for about three years, but after today, it started to output the following error log.

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/**********************/events?alt=json returned "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'calendar-json.googleapis.com' for consumer ‘project_number:*************'.">
```

However, the above log is not always output, and the error rate is about 30%.

We have set the allocation limit to 1,000,000, and there are about 3,000 queries for 24 hours.
Even though the number of times per day has not reached the limit, we are being told to use up our Quota for the day.

The API methods we are using are as follows

- calendar.v3.Events.Insert
- calendar.v3.Events.Get
- calendar.v3.Events.Update
- Delete calendar.v3.Events.
- calendar.v3.CalendarList.
- List calendar.v3.Calendars.
- List calendar.v3.Acl.
- Calendars.Insert calendar.v3.

Calendars.v3.Events.Insert is requested about 2000 times in 24 hours.
Calendars.Insert has been requested 2 times in 24 hours.

Has anyone encountered this before?
Thank you.

Comment: Once you get this message does it reset after a while? or do you have to wait until the next day?

Comment: After a couple of days, the problem stopped occurring. We did not do anything.

Answer (score 3):

We have the exact same problem here.
Everything was working fine and suddenly starting this morning we have these 403 errors (RateLimitExceeded) coming up, with a 50% rate.

Our API usage is exactly the same as before. Our quota sits at 600 requests/minute/user and 1000000 requests per day. All we do is manual, so I don't see how we got past that limit suddenly...

It looks like other people have the same problem, it must be a bug in Google APIs.

The bug has been reported to Google already, see here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182497593

I suggest you star this issue and wait for Google's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I've +1'd this tracker myself.